# Alternative render of JSON response in Django depending on request origination

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to find a way how to return `JsonResponse` which would be either interpreted as JSON when received by Ajax `success` function, or will be rendered to 404 (or any other page) if will be called directly via URL.

The reason I'm looking for this is because on my website I have few places where I am using empty modal view (pop-up) which is later populated with proper HTML content by server based on Ajax request.

In return JSON to my Ajax `success` function I have only HTML responsible for the modal content. So, when displayed as standalone (by typing GET request url directly in browser) it is JSON object.

What I'd like to achieve is display some page in such case (directly typed url for GET request), which will inform user that he's in wrong place, but at the same time will be properly understood by Ajax.

So far I've considered two approaches:

1. Use POST request - this is ok, until I need to render form in modal which is then sent back, also as a POST request, to server to be somehow processed. It requires some ugly workarounds to figure out if request is to render form and send HTML back, or to process form. In this approach I can return 404 page simply using `http_method_not_allowed` function.
2. Render JSON response using `return render(request, 'mytemplate', {'form_html': form_from_string})` - this requires change of Ajax request to use text `dataType` and some extra workarounds on JS side to extract `form_html`.

Is there any 3rd option to get it working as I've imagined it will work?

Comment: You are looking for `JsonResponse` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects ? Not `return render(...)`.

Comment: @MarshalSHI I am using `JsonResponse`. But when you open website, which is returning JsonResponse you are getting just a text. **Not** HTML website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question, but you can use [`request.is_ajax()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) to determine if the request was made using Ajax.

It uses the header `X-Requested-With` to determine if the request was made from ajax context.

Example:

```py
class MyView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            raise Http404
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks!